# ANTLR4: how to say all valid tokens in parser

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have a set of tokens such as '*', ID, '#', [0-9]+ and more. I also have a grammar rule like the following:

```
path: FSLASH FSLASH pathContents FSLASH?;
pathContents: (X)+;
```

How can I set X to be all tokens from my lexer without having to manually type them all in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a parser rule, a period matches any token.